# Rails: Clearance: Can you re-enable the email confirmation feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, clearance

I am trying to using the Clearance gem for a Rails application to handle authentication, but I see at some point they removed a feature for email confirmation.

Does this feature still exist? If so, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well, according to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/thoughtbot-clearance/browse_thread/thread/11a4a9117af15625/044aec944c4143da?lnk=gst&q=confirmation#044aec944c4143da) on Google Groups, the author has indicated that the feature has been removed completely, and that you can implement it yourself using after_create in your User model.